# Make image responsive maintaining aspect ratio, with padding either side

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

Here is a link to the working pen: https://codepen.io/Adam0410/pen/OBqRRN

HTML

```
<div id="imgWrapper">
  <img src="https://thestoryengine.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/The-crossroads-Section-images-02.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#imgWrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  width: 100%;

  padding: 0 20px;
}

#imgWrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1660px;
  height: auto;
}
```

I don't want the image to exceed its original width (hence max-width) but I want it to scale down to the width of the viewport while maintaining its aspect ratio. Currently, the height does not scale with the width, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need display flex to imgWrapper?
Change it to block and it will work as expected. In case you need flex in there add it to other wrapper.

```
#imgWrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I need it to be flex so the image is centered on desktop when it doesn't take up the full width of the screen

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `vm` unit to your `#imgWrapper` making it always responsive:

```
#imgWrapper {
 display: flex;
 justyfy-content: center;
 vm: 100%;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
```